# How to read an array from columns in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have a .csv file with 177 rows and 18,000 odd cols.Given the column label, I should pick that particular column and as a default the first two label columns.

Please help me with this,

Thanks all,

Priya

Comment: -1 - you've apparently tried *nothing*, nor even looked for any possible options

Comment: I have tried storing the column labels in an array list and the values in another array list and tried calling the column via their column label.

Answer (score 1):

So, what's the question? Parse CSV file. You can either implement this yourself or use third party code. 
If you implement it yourself read line by line, split lines `line.split(",")` into elements and put it into data structure that should be a map of lists:

```
Map<String, List<String>> table = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Use column name as a key and column values as a list elements.
LinkedHashMap is preferable here to preserve the order of your columns.

Read first line that contains the column names and create list instances:

```
table.put(columnName, new LinkedList<String>());
```

Additionally create an array of column names:

```
String[] columns = new String[0];
table.keys().toArray();
```

Now continue iterating over your data and populate your table:

```
String[] data = line.split(",");
for (int i = 0;  i < data.length;  i++) {
    table.get(columns[i]).add(data[i]);
}
```

TBD...
Good luck.

Comment: hi, so if i use the linked hash map i can store the column names as keys and the values as the list?i m bit confused on how to store the whole column as a list? Anyhow thank u very much for giving ur time..

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: N, i haven't, I usually read it as a normal file and tokenize it.

Answer (score 0):

You may go for [`OpenCSV`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/)